# Combine arrays into one PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following problem,
I am faced with an array

```
array (size=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=12)
      'A' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1A' (length=2)
      'B' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1b' (length=2)
      'C' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1c' (length=2)
      'D' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1d' (length=2)
      'E' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1e' (length=2)
      'F' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1f' (length=2)
      'G' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1g' (length=2)
      'H' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1h' (length=2)
      'I' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1i' (length=2)
      'J' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1j' (length=2)
      'K' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1k' (length=2)
      'L' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '1l' (length=2)
  3 => 
    array (size=12)
      'A' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2a' (length=2)
      'B' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2b' (length=2)
      'C' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2c' (length=2)
      'D' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2d' (length=2)
      'E' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2e' (length=2)
      'F' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2f' (length=2)
      'G' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2g' (length=2)
      'H' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2h' (length=2)
      'I' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2i' (length=2)
      'J' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2j' (length=2)
      'K' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2k' (length=2)
      'L' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2l' (length=2)
  4 => 
    array (size=12)
      'A' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3a' (length=2)
      'B' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3b' (length=2)
      'C' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3c' (length=2)
      'D' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3d' (length=2)
      'E' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3e' (length=2)
      'F' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3f' (length=2)
      'G' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3g' (length=2)
      'H' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3h' (length=2)
      'I' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3i' (length=2)
      'J' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3j' (length=2)
      'K' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3k' (length=2)
      'L' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '3l' (length=2)
```

This array works fine, I have the indexes[2,3,4] well placed but the problem comes with the internal array, it is taking each letter as a different array when it should be just one array.

The correct way that I can't get to is:

```
array (size=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=12)
      0 => string '1A' (length=2)
      1 => string '1b' (length=2)
      2 => string '1c' (length=2)
      3 => string '1d' (length=2)
      4 => string '1e' (length=2)
      5 => string '1f' (length=2)
      6 => string '1g' (length=2)
      7 => string '1h' (length=2)
      8 => string '1i' (length=2)
      9 => string '1j' (length=2)
      10 => string '1k' (length=2)
      11=> string '1l (length=2)

  3 => 
   array (size=12)
      0 => string '2A' (length=2)
      1 => string '2b' (length=2)
      2 => string '2c' (length=2)
      3 => string '2d' (length=2)
      4 => string '2e' (length=2)
      5 => string '2f' (length=2)
      6 => string '2g' (length=2)
      7 => string '2h' (length=2)
      8 => string '2i' (length=2)
      9 => string '2j' (length=2)
      10 => string '2k' (length=2)
      11=> string '2l (length=2)
  4 => 
    array (size=12)
      array (size=12)
      0 => string '3A' (length=2)
      1 => string '3b' (length=2)
      2 => string '3c' (length=2)
      3 => string '3d' (length=2)
      4 => string '3e' (length=2)
      5 => string '3f' (length=2)
      6 => string '3g' (length=2)
      7 => string '3h' (length=2)
      8 => string '3i' (length=2)
      9 => string '3j' (length=2)
      10 => string '3k' (length=2)
      11=> string '3l (length=2)
```

the way i fill my fors is as follows. any ideas???

```
    $array = [];
    for ($row = 1; $row <= 3; $row++) {
    $letter = "A";
     for ($contt = 0; $contt < 13; $contt++) {
      $array[$row][$letter] = [$sheet->getCell("$letter" . $row)->getValue()];
       $letter++;
     }
    }       
   return $array;
```

This would be another form of the array output, but it is not necessary!

```
array (size=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=12)
      A => string '1A' (length=2)
      B => string '1b' (length=2)
      C => string '1c' (length=2)
      D => string '1d' (length=2)
      E => string '1e' (length=2)
      F => string '1f' (length=2)
      G => string '1g' (length=2)
      H => string '1h' (length=2)
      I => string '1i' (length=2)
      J => string '1j' (length=2)
      K => string '1k' (length=2)
      L=> string '1l (length=2)

  3 => 
   array (size=12)
    ....
```

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to build the array a particular way and you want help how to it?

Comment: I try to get to the second array, but I only get to do what appears in the first array of this post!

Comment: Get it from where?

Comment: So to put it plain & simple  - you just want those plain values under the letter keys, instead of an array? Well then stop _explicitly creating_ that array - which is what you are doing, by putting `[...]` around the value you are assigning there. Your question here basically boils down to, "I don't know the difference between `1` and `[1]`"

Answer (score -2):

Based on your code you shared, the cell value not supposed to store as array.

```
$array = [];
for ($row = 1; $row <= 3; $row++) {
    $letter = "a";
    for ($contt = 0; $contt < 12; $contt++) {
        // Cell value not supposed to be stored as array
        // Uppercase if letter is "A"
        $array[$row + 1][] = $row.($letter === 'a' ? strtoupper($letter) : $letter);
        $letter++;
    }
}
return $array;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).